# Positioning multiple Divs on Background Image

Tags: css

I am trying to position square divs on this background image:
[image]

Like this:

[image]

```
.farmfield{
  background-image: url("http://i.hizliresim.com/aYdRrz.png");
  width:400px;
height: 400px;

}
```

400px x 400px so  50px x 50px 64 square divs.By the way no need to draw anything i just need different clickable regions thats why.

What is the best responsive approach to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with gradient if you want to simply have the visual output and no need for 64 `div`:

```css
.farmfield {
  background: 
   repeating-linear-gradient(to right,#000 0px,#000 2px,transparent 2px,transparent 48px,#000 48px,#000 50px),
   repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,#000 0px,#000 2px,transparent 2px,transparent 48px,#000 48px,#000 50px),
   url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYnNs.png") center/cover;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border:2px solid
}
```

```html
<div class="farmfield">

</div>
```

If you need clickable area then I think CSS grid is a good solution because you simply need to control the grid by adjusting the parent properties.

```css
.farmfield {
  background:
   url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYnNs.png") center/cover;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(8,1fr);
  grid-template-rows:repeat(8,1fr);
  border:2px solid;
}
.farmfield > * {
  border:2px solid;
}
.farmfield > *:hover {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="farmfield">
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

For old browser you can consider float:

```css
.farmfield {
  background:
   url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYnNs.png") center/cover;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:2px solid;
}
.farmfield > * {
  border:2px solid;
  float:left;
  width:calc(400px / 8);
  height:calc(400px / 8);
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.farmfield > *:hover {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="farmfield">
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Drawing square is not required i put it as an example.I would like to make each square clickable thats why i put that image

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach to have clickable areas in your image is too use `maps` and `area`s sets, they are made for that.
You use them by specify the `usemap="#myMapId"` in the img tag and then you create a map that contains each clickable area that you need. Then you attach click events to the area like any Dom element.
Check the documentation of the area tag here:  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp

See a working example here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap